# How to avoid redirection of Url?

Tags: android, url

i have to simply open facebook on my mobile phone, facebook's browser version. but in my mobile i can only open its mobile version.
How can i avoid this redirection of Url.

m using this code now.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}
}
```

Its HelloWebViewClient class is as follows.

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.equals("http://www.facebook.com"))
        {
            //do your own thing here
            view.scrollTo(300, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }           
    }
```

M using Android 2.3.4, My device is google Nexus one.
Kindly suggest me where i am going wrong and what sud i do to avoid this type of URL Redirection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `User-Agent` header before the `loadUrl()`

```
String yourUserAgent
   = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
yourWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(yourUserAgent);
```

I will check what is the bedst User-Agent to use but I think this will work perfectly

***Tested and working***

[image: Tested and working]

Comment: Can you please try it? @LAS_VEGAS I am setting the user-agent! What extraHeaders .. you mean of the loadUrl()? I am not touching `loadUrl` .. just add this code anywhere before calling `loadUrl` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)

Comment: oh, just realised, of course it works you are not using `loadUrl (String url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders)`. That comment was for triying to change it with `loadUrl`. My bad.

Comment: HI Sherif, i use these your line in my code. its work great, thanks u save my ass.

Comment: HI Sherif,hi  m using code for this website           http://timesofindia.com/,  this is not working, its still opens its mobile site.its working for facebook, What can be issue. Kindly Suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Change the user agent string using `WebView.setUserAgentString(String ua)`  to a desktop browser. That way, facebook will not know user is on a mobile phone.

[More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29)

List of all user agent strings:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: HI LAS_VEGAS, m using code for this website timesofindia.com, this is not working, its still opens its mobile site.its working for facebook, What can be issue. Kindly Suggest.